# Как правильно указать вложенный див в примере DOM для смены его имени класса?

Tags: javascript, html5

В ячейке таблицы **tbl** есть вложенные дивы.
Хочу у дива с именем класса **xxx** поменять название класса.
Не получается правильно указать именно его по конструкции DOM.
Получилось дойти до блока дивов, а указать нужный первый див в нём - никак.
Пример.

```js
// Здесь : <div class="xxx">it_is</div>
// хочу поменять class с "xxx" на "yyy".
// .className = "yyy";

// Вот так добираюсь до блока дивов :

function fn() {

    alert('dom :: ' + document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows[1].cells[0].lastChild.previousSibling.innerHTML);

  }
  //

fn();
```

```css
#tbl {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#tbl tbody td {
  height: 54px;
}
.p5 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
.p6 {
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
.xxx {
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>H1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="width:90%; float: left; background: yellow;">
          <div class=p5 style="background: green;">sss</div>
          <div class=p6 style="background: orange;">iii</div>
        </div>

        <div style="height:20px; width:3%; float: left; margin-top:10px; background: blue;">i</div>

        <div style="width:5%; float: left; margin-top:8px; background: yellow;">
          <div class="xxx">it_is</div>
          <div style="width:29px; margin-top:-20px; font-size:9px; font-weight:bold; background: #c2c2c2">zzz</div>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>F2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), параметром является строка с css селектором. например

```
var d = document.querySelector('#tbl .xxx');
```

Пример:

```js
// Здесь : <div class="xxx">it_is</div>
// хочу поменять class с "xxx" на "yyy".
// .className = "yyy";

// Вот так добираюсь до блока дивов :

function fn() {

    var xxx = document.querySelector('#tbl .xxx');

    var zzz = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows[1].cells[0].lastChild.previousSibling.firstElementChild;

    console.log(xxx === zzz,zzz); // вернет true, так как это один и тот же элемент
    xxx.className = 'yyy';

  }
  //

setTimeout(fn, 2000);
```

```css
#tbl {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#tbl tbody td {
  height: 54px;
}
.p5 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
.p6 {
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3%;
}
.xxx {
  height: 35px;
}
.yyy {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>H1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="width:90%; float: left; background: yellow;">
          <div class=p5 style="background: green;">sss</div>
          <div class=p6 style="background: orange;">iii</div>
        </div>

        <div style="height:20px; width:3%; float: left; margin-top:10px; background: blue;">i</div>

        <div style="width:5%; float: left; margin-top:8px; background: yellow;">
          <div class="xxx">it_is</div>
          <div style="width:29px; margin-top:-20px; font-size:9px; font-weight:bold; background: #c2c2c2">zzz</div>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>F2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Ваш пример работает, как мне нужно, спасибо. Можно уточнить, для понимания, вот моим способом : document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows[1].cells[0].lastChild.previousSibling._что-то еще_.className = 'yyy';

Comment: _вот это *_что-то еще_* для движения по группе дивов, оно существует, или так не делают?

Comment: @Alex, вообще говоря странно почему вы используете одни функции: `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` и не хотите использовать другие например `getElementsByClassName` - которая позволила бы сразу нужный элемент по классу найти. Но да, элементы можно перебирать и на одном уровне и на вложенных

Comment: @Alex, обновил сниппет в ответе

Comment: конечно правильно через getElementsByClassName, сейчас только обнаружил особенность в своём исходном коде, когда блок дивов был обрамлён <!--  -->, то алёрт его не выводил, это и сбило с толку. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alex, если дивы были в комментарии то их никак не возможно было бы достать, только пытаясь распарсить комментарий, либо выбирая его текстовое содержание и, опять же, получая из текста элемент

Comment: теперь понятно, буду знать, thanks.